# JNLP .java.policy no effect

Tags: java, permissions, java-web-start, jnlp, policy

After updating to Jave 7 Update 51 a client's application stopped to work. I could enable it to run either via exception white list or by deploying a DeploymentRuleSet.jar using a self signed certificate and importing it via Java Control Panel.

In either case no permissions set in $HOME/.java_policy are actually granted. Is this a hard limitation imposed by this update or do I miss something?

Comment: What was the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this posting](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) from Oracle on the new security requirements for Web Start and Applets.  You have to sign the jars, not with a self-signed certificate and also update the MANIFEST.MF for all downloaded jars to include the new permissions tag, plus some other optional tags.

Comment: I've read that, but in section "Desktop Administrators" it's said an administrator can also whitelist applications "even if you cannot update the application to adhere to these requirements.". I did create a set of Deployment Set Rules getting the application to run, but it still doesn't get those permissions specified in $HOME/.java.policy.

Comment: We have the following in our policy file `grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`  and we also have `<security><all-permissions/></security>` in our JNLP file that gets downloaded.  This provides us with everything we needed.